# Does left-foot braking result in faster driving?

Tags: road-vehicles

Does braking using your left foot (like Formula 1 drivers would) make you a better/faster driver?
And why?

Is it only better/faster if you don't have a *clutch*? So then it would not be impressive at all if you use your left foot to brake for mundane driving?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Better for the car? Safer?

Comment: No. `Does it "make you a better/faster driver?"`

Comment: @Adam: As in, what does "better driver" mean?

Comment: @MrHen Faster is the main thing. More efficient, quicker gear changes, more control of the car, etc.

Comment: @Adam: For automatic transmissions, for an older driver (like me), there are too many stories of drivers in parking lots trying to hit the brake and hitting the accelerator instead, with tragic consequences. So I've trained myself to brake with my left foot, and I recommend it, for safety and lower reaction time.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Makes sense. If I were learning to drive from scratch  with an automatic, I think I'd (choose to) brake with my left. I've tried to use my left foot to brake from time to time, but it's hazardous for me at this stage. I'm not used to braking with my left so I'd brake too hard and then, as is second nature to someone used to manual transmittions, when something goes wrong you immediately push in the clutch and then brake with the right, but my left foot would be already on the brake so I'd just push even futher down and come to a complete stop and conk out (in fifth gear)

Comment: @Adam: Yeah. For standard transmission, I do it the old way, which is plenty safe because you can't accidentally go just by hitting the wrong pedal. (Then there's the good old heel-and-toe mathod.)

Comment: Left-footed braking is essentially a racing technique. The footwork involved in driving a racing car with a manual transmission is...complex.
For daily driving around... Unnecessary and IMO...Uncomfortable.

Comment: *"Is it only better/faster if you don't have a clutch?"* Racers often have the clutch/shifting paddles on the steering wheel.  So technically they do have a clutch. Using the gas and brake *simultaneously* has some benefit for racing (where wear and tear, fuel consumption, etc are less important than fine grained control and performance) but the benefits for regular drivers would probably come down merely to reaction time. The main reason people continue to be trained to use the same foot is due to the fear reaction, causing people to stomp both feet if they didn't move one foot over to brake.

Comment: It takes time to move a foot between pedals, and tenths of seconds do count in emergency braking situations.  (Freeway speed is roughly 90 feet/27 meters per second, so a tenth of a second is 9 feet/2.7 meters, and I've sometimes stopped less than that distance from the car in front.  Another tenth of a second delay would have meant an accident.)

Comment: @David Yes, but it's even worse when you press both the gas and the brake at the same time.

Comment: @Adam Davis: No it's not. In modern cars (with electronic fuel injection systems), the brake overrides the throttle. Not only is this a safety feature, it also helps to reduce emissions.

Comment: @MSalters Having written code that goes into vehicle computers I can say quite confidently that your statement is tragically false on many models of vehicles on the road today.  The recent Toyota electronic throttle control debacle has put the focus on this particular aspect of whether the throttle should perform differently based on the brake due to several instances where driver error (pressing both gas and brake resulted in "unintended" acceleration) resulted in a crash. Car companies are changing how they do this to avoid liability, but you **CANNOT** count on this in any vehicle.

Comment: Wasn't that one of the reasons why the Prius story got so big? I.e. Toyota forgot to include a safety feature that reasonable drivers would expect in a modern car?

Comment: @MSalters I don't think any faults were found with any Priuses, and that driver error was to blame in practically every instance. It may be worth posting a question on this!

Comment: Wait... is it not dangerous to do that? I was told it's dangerous to left-foot brake, with no reason given (but I surmised it might be bad for the engine if both happened at once).

Comment: @Yamikuronue: I think it's one of those things that have been said and repeated, but lost their reason in the dust. I do left-foot braking (when driving an automatic transmission). If I blow out a transmission, it's only money. If I ever hit anyone I don't know how I could live with it.

Comment: I hate following a left-foot braker. You can spot them a mile away - their brake lights flicker on *all the time*, even on a straight piece of road, even when they're not slowing down. And in fact in Rally driving with heel-and-toe they still clutch with their left foot and use their right foot for *both* the brake and accelerator *at the same time*. So my doubts are already high on any form of "left foot braking" better for anything outside go-karts and open wheelers.

Comment: @Mark: I'm a left-foot braker. I don't think I ride the brake light, but I can't be sure. Maybe it's annoying, I don't know. I'm pretty sure it's safer. If I have to thread through a parking lot with people standing around, including kids, I know I can stop really fast. Several times I have avoided collisions by the fast reaction time. If it avoids an accident I don't give a hoot about damaging the engine or surprising a tailgater. As an aside, keep in mind that every young driver will be an old driver, luck permitting.

Comment: @Mike if you ride the break light, it is certainly NOT safer for the person driving behind you who cant figure out when you are really breaking, and cant react. I can stop really fast too, with my right foot.

Comment: @Sam: When you're 30 I'm sure you can stop really fast, but not when you're 68 or more. You do plan to be 68, I assume, and you do plan to still be driving then, and I assume you would rather minimize your risk of hitting people. (I also assume you're not a tailgater ;-)

Comment: @MarkHenderson I'm pretty sure that's left-foot braking done incorrectly, which shouldn't count seeing as any form of braking can be done incorrectly. The problem with left-foot braking is that once people "think" they've grasped it they think its ok to leave their left foot hovering above the brake pedal waiting to brake, when what they should actually do is treat it like its a clutch in a manual and only bring the foot up when the correct situation arises (obviously if you've mastered the technique, you should be able to do this really fast in case of an emergency)

Comment: Left foot breaking can reduce turbo lag on a turbo charged car when cornering at high speed. When combined with a manual transmission and clutch, I believe this is referred to as "heel-toe". By keeping the engine speed up you can keep the car in your powerband. Neither technique is necessary unless you are racing and if you are doing these things on the road you are endangering the other people around you.

Comment: In the military we used left-foot braking to turn better on snow and ice (not exclusive) at higher speeds.

Comment: The Team O'Neil Rally School just posted a nice instructional video about left foot braking, I'll just leave it right here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xl7O01h7MU4

Answer (score 5):

[Left-Foot Braking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-foot_braking) can, in certain situations, result in better/faster racing times.

> One common race situation that requires left-foot braking is when a
>   racer is cornering under power. If the driver doesn't want to lift off
>   the throttle, potentially causing trailing-throttle over-steer,
>   left-foot braking can induce a mild over-steer situation, and help the
>   car "tuck", or turn-in better. Mild left-foot braking can also help
>   reduce under-steer.
>
> In rallying left-foot braking is very beneficial, especially to
>   front-wheel drive vehicles. It is closely related to the handbrake
>   turn, but involves locking the rear wheels using the foot brake
>   (retarding actually, to reduce traction, rarely fully locking - best
>   considered a misapplication), which is set up to apply a significant
>   pressure bias to the rear brakes. The vehicle is balanced using engine
>   power by use of the accelerator pedal, operated by the right foot. The
>   left foot is thus brought into play to operate the brake.
>
> It is not as necessary to use this technique with Rear-wheel drive and
>   All wheel drive rally vehicles because they can be easily turned
>   rapidly by using excess power to the wheels and the use of opposite
>   lock steering, however the technique is still beneficial when the
>   driver needs to decelerate and slide at the same time. In rear wheel
>   drive, left foot braking can be used when the car is at opposite lock
>   and about to spin. Using throttle and brake will lock the front tires
>   but not the rears, thus giving the rears more traction and bringing
>   the front end around.
>
> In restrictor plate NASCAR events, drivers were known to
>   left-foot-brake at times, particularly in heavy traffic situations.
>   Rather than lift off the throttle, which could lose considerable power
>   and speed (due to the restrictor plates), a mild tap of the brakes
>   while the right foot was still planted flat on the accelerator, could
>   help avoid contact and bump drafting.

---

As far as normal road use goes, left-foot breaking can only realistically be [recommended for cars equipped with automatic transmissions](http://www.honestjohn.co.uk/faq/driving-automatics-safely), which have far less control than manual transmissions.

> The problem with automatic transmission is that, unless the driver
>   drives 'two footed', he or she has far less control over the car than
>   over a manual – which is why we read of many deaths and injuries
>   caused by 'out of control' automatics. What usually happens is that
>   during the engine's warm-up phase, or if the engine has been
>   over-fuelling, the electronic control unit raises engine revs to above
>   the point at which drive is taken up in the transmission, and the car
>   starts to move. The driver may then panic, attempt to brake heavily,
>   but hit the accelerator instead of the brake, and the car either
>   crashes or runs someone over. (The phenomenon even has a name: 'Sudden
>   Acceleration Syndrome'.) You cannot predict precisely when the car's
>   ECU will increase revs independently, so my advice is to only buy an
>   automatic if you can teach yourself to brake with your left foot at
>   least while [sic] manoeuvring, which keeps the car fully under control.

Comment: In terms of safety, these are the exact reasons I've taught myself left-foot braking (in automatics). Whenever these accidents happen, and they happen frequently, it's a tragedy for everyone involved.

Comment: ... Or, as many American-market cars force you to do, always keep the brake applied while shifting between Park, Reverse and Drive. I've heard of and seen videos of SAS, and in every last instance it's ultimately the driver's fault for not knowing where their feet are. AT cars sold in the U.S. typically have large, firm brake pedals positioned further up than the accelerator, making it more obvious to the driver by feel. Automatics are perfectly safe without having to learn left-foot braking; the number of documented SAS incidents is a drop in the ocean of AT cars on the road.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, efficient left-foot braking does typically require that you're not also on the clutch. In F1 cars, the clutch is controlled by either of two paddles under the "gear up" and "gear down" paddles, and so it's more natural to give the left foot responsibility for braking. As an aside, the average F1 steering wheel, with multiple electronic linkages to the transmission and powertrain, fuel injection system, brake balance system, front and rear wing adjustments, communications system, various LCD readouts including upshift and pit cues, and the fact that like everything in the cockpit it's custom-made for the driver out of the most lightweight materials, [costs in the neighborhood of US$50k](http://kotaku.com/5785331/the-70000-steering-wheels-of-formula-1).

With a clutch pedal on the floor, you typically have to press both clutch and brake at the same time as you're both slowing and downshifting for a corner. The GT and rally drivers, who start with production vehicles and can't make extensive control setup mods like paddle shifters, do put in aftermarket clutches and make very precise adjustments to the pedal throws, giving the clutch, brakes and accelerator the same throw length (short). The pedals are also placed very closely together, allowing drivers to use an "overlap" position of their feet on the pedals; press the outside of the right foot for gas, press the outside of the left foot for clutch, press the inside of *either* for brake. This in turn more or less allows the driver to use whatever foot's handy to brake, left or right. If they're off the accelerator and downshifting for a hairpin, right foot. If they're slowing for a chicane or a drift turn but still under power, left foot.

In the average civilian vehicle, these adjustments aren't available; the pedals are spaced further apart (especially for large American clod-stompers), differently-shaped and differently-placed, and have different weights and throw lengths. Despite this, Rally Racing News [recommends left-foot braking](http://www.rallyracingnews.com/lfb.html) when driving a front-wheel drive car in a racing scenario. The basic idea in a FWD is that when both brake and accelerator are applied, the front wheels keep turning despite the braking, because they're under power, but the rear wheels slow, and so lose some of their traction, causing the rear end to kick out (oversteer; a hard thing to do in most American FWDs, which are strongly biased for understeer for safety reasons).

In a rear-wheel-drive car, this effect is even more pronounced but for the opposite reason; the car slows, transferring weight to the front wheels, and with the rear wheels still under power from the accelerator they will lose traction, kicking out the rear end. This in fact makes RWD cars really sensitive to applying brakes, accelerator and steering wheel at the same time; the general strategy in a RWD is to brake before beginning to turn, shifting weight to the turning wheels, then turn and accelerate through the corner as you straighten out. Braking while turning hard will cause the rear tires to lose too much traction, putting the car sideways in the corner, and when you add accelerator to try to power out of it, the car will swap ends.

Comment: Is it fair to say this entire answer depends on being in rally conditions, where you expect to skid at every corner, but is not applicable to driving on paved roads at legal speeds?

Comment: @Oddthinking - Purt' much.